# GPU Programming Strategy

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I am trying to program a type of neural network using c in CUDA. I have one basic question. For the programming, I can either use big arrays or different naming strategy. For example for the weights, I can put all the weights in one big array or use different arrays for different layers with different names such as weight1 which is for layer one and weight2 for layer2 and so on. The first strategy is a little bit troublesome while the second one is easier for me. However, I am wondering if I use the different naming strategy, does it make the program slower to run on GPU?

Comment: Write the code, then measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my 2 cents. 
The drawbacks of having 1 very large array:

- harder to resize, so if you intent on resizing indiviual layers. Go for a large block.
- As Daniel said it might be hard to find a contiguous block of memory(take in mind that something might feel large. But isn't from a techinal/hardware perspective.

The drawbacks of Seperate arrays or containers.

- If you have a very granulated, unpredictable access pattern. The access times can be slower if it takes multiple steps to find a single location in an array. For example, if you have a list of pointers to a list of pointers, to a list of pointers. You have to take three(slightly expensive) steps every time. This can be avoided with proper coding.

In general I would be in favor of splitting up.

Answer (score 2):

As long as all the arrays are allocated only once and not resized, the difference in performance should be negligible.

If you are constantly reallocating memory and resizing arrays holding the weights, then there might be a performance benefit in managing your own memory within the big array.

That however that is very implementation specific, if you don't know what you are doing, managing your own memory/arrays could make your code slower and less robust. Also if your NN is huge, you might have trouble finding a contiguous block of memory large enough to hold your memory/array block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. I am going to allocate the arrays just once.